# In the MSAL Python library, are the ConfidentialClientApplication and its underlying TokenCache objects thread safe?

Tags: python, authentication, azure-ad-msal

When using Microsoft Authentication Library for Python (MSAL) on the server side, is it safe to share single ConfidentialClientApplication object between several threads?

In other words, if different users acquire new tokens in parallel threads at the same moment, will the underlying TokenCache remain consistent?

Answer (score 0):

Based on github PRs history, it should be thread safe: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java/pull/79

Comment: Thanks for digging, but the quoted PR is for MSAL for Java, and the question was about MSAL for Python.